# the majority of + plural noun + singular vs. plural verb

Tags: singular-vs-plural, collective-nouns

If I say "the majority of" followed by a plural noun, should it then be followed by a singular or a plural verb?

Some examples:

> The majority of cars **is** blue.

> The majority of cars **are** blue.

> The majority of cars **runs** on gasoline.

> The majority of cars **run** on gasoline.

> The majority of patients **is** incurable.

> The majority of patients **are** incurable.

I feel that in all cases I should use the plural verb form because the property applies to each individual component rather than to the mass.

PS: There is a similar thread
[The majority: plural or singular](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152504/the-majority-plural-or-singular)

Comment: In terms of agreement, "majority" is a borderline case. Generally, there is plural override, but singular agreement can occur when the determiner is "a", as in "A large majority of voters is required for a decisive win".

Comment: According to these grammarians, "the majority of" uses a singular verb and "a majority of" uses a plural one https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/09/majority-rules.html

Answer (score 2):

On its own, "the majority" is a *collective noun*, which means it can be used as singular or plural depending on the context and your intent. This is explained [at this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310009/a-group-of-dogs-emerge-or-emerges/310122#310122).

But if "the majority" is followed by "...of X", then it's always used in the plural. So all your examples should be in the plural.

Comment: https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/09/majority-rules.html This blog states that "the majority" should use a singular verb. What do you think?

Comment: @pierrot5 That blog says using "the" is "usually a tip-off" that its singular. This means "people usually *choose 'the' when it's a singular verb*, which the opposite of saying people *should use a singular verb with 'the'*. The blog also says that "**a** majority" is usually plural, "especially with of". I think this is too weak. Like I say in my answer, I think "a majority **of**" and "the majority **of**" are *always* plural.

Comment: Could the controversy come from this? **In British English a group noun can take either a singular or a plural verb. But in American English a group noun takes a singular verb.** https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310009/a-group-of-dogs-emerge-or-emerges/310122#310122

Comment: @pierrot5 No. I'm Canadian (we speak American English), and I'm saying that "the majority of X" will **always be plural**. And... that's not even true about American English speakers, as I've commented on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers posted so far are neglecting something important about the word "majority", which is that it *doesn't* always indicate a collection (or a collective for that matter). There are of course many times when it does, and in those times, you must use a plural verb (because "the majority" is countable and plural). However, there is a second context in which the expression "the majority" may appear which indicates the larger or largest part of a whole. In those cases, you use the singular verb.

Here are some valid examples:

- The majority of cars on the street are white.

The plural is used because "most" means the a countable number of cars, all of which are white.

- The majority of cars run on gasoline.

The plural is used because "most" indicates a countable number of cars.

And here are some valid examples of using the singular:

- The majority of the pie is burnt.

The singular is used because "most" indicates the largest part or portion of a single thing.

- The majority of the fence needs repair.

The singular is used because here again, "most" indicates the largest part or portion of a single thing.

Answer (score -1):

These type of questions are frequently asked on the site. Some collective expressions take singular, but many, including this one, idiomatically will take either.

Comment: I think you mean "Of all the cars on the road, the majority is/are white".

Comment: According to the similar thread, it can also be idiomatically singular.

Comment: Take a look at this rule. It conflicts with yours. https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/09/majority-rules.html

Comment: I do realise I have got this wrong and I am going to edit it to indicate that either is possible. My apologies.

Comment: I am not sure that either is possible. According to the link, **the majority of** uses a **singular** verb and **a majority of** uses **a plural** one. But maybe this rule is also wrong because all answers that I find on this subject are inconsistent...

Comment: Having said this, I don't know if "the majority of" and "a majority of" are synonyms.